# How to get text from individual users

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quick.db

I'm trying to make a notes command for specific users, but my Discord bot makes the notes any note that a user public has said. How do I fix this? I already know the problem with my code, but I don't know how to fix it.

```js
if (command == "Note") {
   const notes = db.fetch('userInfo');
   while (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Here are your notes: " + notes);
   db.set('userInfo', args.join(' '));
   message.channel.send((args.join(' ')) + (" successfully noted!"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a row called `userInfo`, this row gets updated whenever someone executes the command. If you want it to link with a user, you're better of using the id of the user because everyone has a different ID. I suggest using something like:

```
   const notes = db.fetch(`userInfo.${message.author.id}`)
   while (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Here are your notes: " + notes )
   db.set('userInfo.${message.author.id}', args.join(' '))
   message.channel.send(args.join(' ') + " successfully noted!")
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. in the end, I ended up using this code: 

const notes = db.fetch(`userInfo${message.author.id}`);
   while (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Here are your notes: " + notes);
   db.set(`userInfo${message.author.id}`, args.join(' '));
   message.channel.send((args.join(' ')) + (" successfully noted!"));